# Are these too many wires, just insulation tape, should i address?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

[image: current state of 4gang switch box]

Was opening this up to replace one with a smart switch that needs a neutral.  All the 8 leads go into a single bundle which was just covered with rubbery fabric insulation tape.  Upon removal of tape I can see some evidence of past arcing (burn).

Yes all 4 switches are on the same breaker/circuit.

do I

1. add my neutral to this bundle?
2. break up the bundle to multiple bundles with daisy chained nuts?
3. tape it back up and pretend I didn't see anything
4. other?

Thanks!

Comment: What else is in the box? Those wires look far too yellow to be (code legal) neutrals.

Comment: it's just a 4 gang box with 4 light switches (3 regular single pole switches, one "3-way").  they seem mostly white in person but aged. Some of the yellow appearance just might be my phone "correcting" for the wall color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2. break up the bundle to multiple bundles with daisy chained nuts?

While you are it:

- Make sure that all grounds are connected properly. Note that with metal boxes, most switches can ground via the yoke, which eliminates some ground wires.
- If there are any "back stab" connections in use, switch them to screws.

Comment: any particular sequence for breaking up the bundle? is 3 old plus one for daisy chain seem legit? the grounds seem OK.  how bad are the back stabs?

Comment: Doesn't matter how the neutrals are grouped, as long as they all end up together. Check the wire nuts (Ideal is the big name, but others are fine if UL listed) to see how many wires you can put in each wire nut.

Comment: And back stabs are horrible. You may not have any, but just pointing it out to deal with while you have things opened up.

Comment: @nhed   Back stabs are a weaker means of connection.  Usually a thin spring touching the wire instead of a whole thick screw head.  The springs also known for getting weaker over time.  If found, quite a few connection problems in circuits are due to back stabs.  Some devices(not cheap) have screw in back stabs that are okay.

Comment: This might go without saying, but nip the wires back a bit and re-strip. Arcing degrades bare copper and I’m apt to be suspicious about the method of stripping originally.

Comment: @nhed -- you may wish to use an Ideal In-Sure or other equivalent multi-port connector instead of multiple wirenuts here

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I understand the appeal of these based on speed and perhaps even easier in tighter spaces but they seem very similar to back-stab being warned against here.  Are they as reliable as the nuts?  They seem to have much lower surface area conducting the current between the leads  (p.s. in my youth I was an apprentice-electrician "across the pond" using the European style screw terminals, which I'm still fond of, but rarely see).

(p.s. Already done yesterday with wire nuts)

Comment: @nhed 99% of the time (and UL certifies this), the backstab fails as a simple "open circuit" not a receptacle-igniting arcing.  So the #1 reason we say to avoid backstabs is the nuisance factor - finding a failed backstab connection takes hours of work because for most novices it amounts to converting everything to screws.  (backstabs are basically un-inspect-able).  Better switches and receptacles use screw-down connections, cleverly tucked under the screw. You can also get Alumiconns or Ilsco "Mac Block Connectors" which are full and proper screw lugs.

Comment: @nhed -- the In-Sure type connectors seem to be better designed than backstab holes on wiring devices, at least

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica are those designed to bridge aluminum to copper or general purpose copper-copper?

Comment: @nhed yes, Alumiconns and MAC Block connectors (along with their big brother Polaris) are rated for both Cu and AL.  (but if you use them with all-Cu, I promos not to tell lol)  They basically look like 2-3 holes of a panel ground bar, but they are encased in insulation so you don't have to spend 10 minutes wrapping them with a mile of tape lol.